# DateTime substitution from a string in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Imagine that I have this string coming from some external api. The string format is always same including the HTML tags and everything.

```
"<p>The update time is <strong>Tuesday 04/28/15 08:30 AM PDT</strong>, please disregard the old timing.</p>"
```

How do I extract the DateTime from the string (`Tuesday 04/28/15 08:30 AM PDT`) and convert it to EST and then wrap it back to string around the `<strong>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is exactly the same every time, I would just `gsub` out the parts of the string you don't want.

```
string_from_api.gsub!(/(.*<strong>|<\/strong>.*)/, '')
```

Then use `strptime` like so:

```
date_time = DateTime.strptime(string_from_api, "%A %m/%d/%y %I:%M %p %Z")
```

(My favorite [strftime](http://strftime.net/) resource.)

Then, assuming you're using Rails, you can change the timezone with

```
est_time = date_time.in_time_zone('EST')
```

Then you just have to put it all back together:

```
time_formatted = est_time.strftime("%A %m/%d/%y %I:%M %p %Z")
"<p>The update time is <strong>#{time_formatted}</strong></p>"
```

Comment: The following regex can be used to extract the time string: /strong\>(.+)\<\/strong/.match(input)[1]

Comment: Yep. That's better. Updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert_time_message(message)
  regex = /<strong\>(.*?)\<\/strong>/
  time_format = '%a %m/%d/%y %H:%M %p %Z'

  parsed_time = DateTime.strptime(message.match(regex)[1], time_format)
  converted_time = parsed_time.in_time_zone('EST')

  message.gsub(regex, "<strong>#{converted_time.strftime(time_format)}</strong>")
end

convert_time_message("<p>The update time is <strong>Tuesday 04/28/15 08:30 AM PDT</strong>, please disregard the old timing.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to parse the date you've been given and then [DateTime.strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) to output it again once you've modified it to your satisfaction. Something like:

```
s = "<p>The update time is <strong>Tuesday 04/28/15 08:30 AM PDT</strong>, please disregard the old timing."
s.sub(/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/) do |s|
  # Parse the date in between the <strong> tags
  in_date = DateTime.strptime($1, "%A %m/%d/%y %I:%M %p %Z")
  edt_time = in_date + 3.hours
  "<strong>#{edt_time.strftime("%A %m/%d/%y %I:%M %p EDT")}</strong>"
end
```